# how to prevent scrolling on other element bound to the same container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sorry if the context already exists in other SO thread. I didnt found anyone, so I am posting it.

I have two elements(tabs) in the container(body) both are overflowing. when I try to scroll one tab, the hidden tab content also scrolling. I think, this is because both elements bound to the window.

```
 <div class="header">
    <ul>
      <li data-tabid="tab1" class="tab">Tab1</li>
      <li data-tabid="tab2" class="tab">Tab2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <div class="tabContainer">
       <div class="tab1 tabpanel">
         <!-- overflowing content -->
       </div>
       <div class="tab2 tabpanel">
         <!-- overflowing content -->
       </div>


    </div>
```

CSS

```
body{
  height:100%;
  overflow-x:auto;
  }
.header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  height:50px;
}
.tabpanel{
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kongaraju/P6XWH/)**

How to prevent  scrolling on hidden element?

Comment: Please add _relevant_ HTML & CSS to your post.

Comment: There's no hidden neither scrolling tabs defined with this CSS you've posted.

Comment: I am doing it in javascript and I activate relevant tab panel on click.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe you could save an example code at [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: :) here is fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/kongaraju/P6XWH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo, the solution is come up with setting both ends fixed and scrolling content. This should give effect like bound to the container.

```
.tabpanel{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
  display:none;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.tabpanel .inner{
 width:100%;
height:150%;
margin-top:60px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kongaraju/P6XWH/2/

Answer (score 1):

Bascially you didnt set the height of your tabs, and neither did you apply an overflow to it. Doing that would solve the issue.

If you prefer to have the tabs 100% height, you would need a div within a div. In the outer div set your 100% height, in the inner div set a top padding of the height of the tab-selection.

Like this:

```
<div class="tab">
  <div class="inner">
    * tab content *
  </div>
</div>
```

With css

```
.tab { height:100%; }
.inner { margin-top:20px; overflow:auto; }
```

Comment: I want to prevent scrolling not bounding to the container.

Comment: The only way to prevent the general scroll is to make sure the height doesn't exceed the total body height. Give the tab itself a height lower than the body height and an overflow and it should work i guess...

Comment: did u understood my question?

Comment: There are multiple scrollbars available. You can scroll within a div container by setting the overflow. But this means the height of the container div shouldnt be higher than the height of your document body. So you scroll within the div instead of the whole document. Right now your whole document is scrolling...

Comment: I dont want to scroll inside div,thats too ugly, I just want prevent scrolling hidden tab.

Comment: Thats not possible. If you scroll the whole page you scroll all other tabs with it. The only thing you might be able to do is let jQuery scroll to top when you click one of the tabs. For scrolling inside the div i created a fiddle branch for you http://jsfiddle.net/dargno/FLFEw/

Comment: look at the answer, you to did the same but the answer is little tricky. Thanks @joris +1